# Does instead of do in positive

Tags: grammar

Resently I saw a cartoon and coulndt understand why is there used does instead of do? I think this is not an auxiliary verb and its a positive sentense. Is this dialectical form? Or very informal variety of English?

"Leonardo's the hero in blue. DOES anything it takes to get his ninja through"

Comment: The word *he* is elided. “[He] does anything it takes ...”.  It’s does to agree with the third person.

Comment: *Recently* I saw a cartoon and *couldn't* understand why *it uses* does instead of do?

Answer (score 1):

The quoted text is part of a rap song. Elision such as omission of personal pronouns is often found in casual or informal speech, slogans, song lyrics, etc.

[Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles Rap](http://www.metrolyrics.com/teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-rap-lyrics-anonymous.html)

Does is the correct verb form. "Leonardo's the hero in blue. [He] does anything it takes to get his ninja through".

Comment: This kind of elision is something that, at least where I am from (New Zealand), would not be used, even in casual or informal speech. The only situation it feels valid to use is in a musical bit, such as what the quote seems to be.

Comment: It's "rap", apparently. [Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles Rap](http://www.metrolyrics.com/teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-rap-lyrics-anonymous.html). This sort of thing is common in advertising slogans, song lyrics, etc.  Compare e.g "Gillette. [It's] The best a man can get", likewise incorporated in a "rap" song (Dr Disrespect). Also

Comment: Yup, I thought it was. Never hear it outside of those contexts. Maybe you should change your answer to make that more clear?

Comment: @severen This kind of elision is exceedingly commonplace in varieties of English throughout the world. I very much doubt that NZE is different. You’re not likely to notice it in casual speech, though, just like you’re not likely to notice repeated words, the number of _uh_’s used in a sentence, etc. It flies under the radar because it’s so transparent. In some cases, it’s almost mandatory; “always have/has (been), always will (be)”, for example, is close enough to idiomacy without pronouns that adding them in actually makes it jar.